# Present transparent modal view from another modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I'm attempting to present a transparent modal view over another modal view. I'm using storyboards.

I have added this to my first modal view:

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sendUserMessage" sender:self];
```

And  this to my second modal view (the one I want to appear over the first modal view having the first transparent in background)

```
// Make the main view's background clear, the second view's background transparent.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIView* backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    backView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
    [self.view addSubview:backView];
```

But it appears that I cannot interact with my UI, as well as the back screen goes black after it fully loads (although is transparent at first).

I assume it's because I'm doing it from another modal view  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presenting view controller's view will be removed from the window by default.

You can change this by setting the presented view controller's `modalPresentationStyle` to either `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext` or `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen`. Both keep the covered content onscreen.

Edit: The above styles are both introduced in iOS 8. If you want the presenting view controller's view to stay put in iOS 7, you'll have to use the Custom presentation style and provide a [transitioningDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate).

Comment: Tried changing it up to both, neither worked. I figured I get rid of the alpha backView so I'm just setting the views background color to clear. The textfields on my modal view transition in over the view how I expected it too, but as soon as it's fully done transitioning, the back modal view still goes black.

Comment: Are you running on iOS 7? I should've mentioned, these styles were introduced in iOS 8.

Comment: No I am running Xcode 6 with iOS 8, odd it isn't working right.

Comment: Strange. Any chance you're setting the property on the presenting view controller instead of the presented view controller? Also, make sure you're setting the property before beginning the presentation. If you're setting the property in the presented view controller's viewDidLoad, for example, it'll be too late.

Comment: I've tried putting it in both and it didn't work. I put them in viewWillAppear. The background modal view still goes black after loading. The modal view on top that is presented is fine though and can be edited, just can't see the back modal view it still goes black for some reason.

Comment: I ended up calling it in prepareForSegue instead since I was using storyboards, and it worked that way. For some reason it didn't work in the viewWillAppear in the presented vc.